# ffprobe throws SegFault on Ubuntu but not Windows

Tags: ubuntu, ffprobe

I'm trying to run the [VideoPose3D](https://github.com/facebookresearch/VideoPose3D) model on a compute cluster at my university, but I've run into an issue where the infer_video.py script (run inside [Detectron](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron)) breaks due to ffprobe. The command in question is:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0 filename_here
```

It's supposed to return a tuple of width,height of the input video. This script worked fine in the past, but on the videos I'm using now, I get a segfault. For context, here is the output of running it on the compute cluster (Ubuntu):

```
$ ffprobe data/test/00001/00001.mp4
ffprobe version 4.0.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/share/pkg.7/ffmpeg/4.0.3/install --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-pic --enable-shared --enable-lto
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Segmentation fault
```

Here's the output of the same command on my local machine (Windows 10):

```
$ ffprobe data\test\00001\00001.mp4
ffprobe version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'data\test\00001\00001.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:02:52.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1643 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1512 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

This leads me to believe it has something to do with the version of ffprobe, but I have no control over the version installed on the compute cluster. It also doesn't explain why it worked once on a video previously. Does anyone have any insight? I also have the full debug output of running ffprobe on the compute cluster in a [gist, here.](https://gist.github.com/ROODAY/df7cd48095e0f15b0d069b37b0dd2430)

EDIT:
Further context that may be useful, and leads me to believe it's a version issue, the videos that populate my data directory are acquired with youtube-dl. When I try to use youtube-dl on the compute cluster, it fails because ffmpeg throws an error when attempting to mux the audio and video streams. No such error happens when I run the script locally (with a newer version of ffmpeg).

The one time ffmpeg worked on the compute cluster, the video in question didn't have an audio stream, just video. Is this a known issue with older versions of ffmpeg? Should I get around this by just using a docker container with a higher version of ffmpeg, or are there any other workarounds people suggest?

Comment: 4.0.3's a bit old...gdb might tell you where it's blowing up if you want to dig that deep...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't end up digging into ffmpeg to see what the error was, but I have confirmed that the error doesn't occur on version 4.2.1. Luckily I was able to request an upgrade on the compute cluster I'm using and was able to get around this issue.